# Take a value form a vector only if it is also present in another vector (in R)

Tags: r, vector

I have 2 vectors "x" and "y". I would like to take all letters that are in "x" only if they are also in "y".

```
x<- c(a, b, c, d, e)
y<- c(a, z, m, d, e, g)

result
r <- c(a, d, e)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `intersect`

```
intersect(x, y)
#[1] "a" "d" "e"
```

Comment: Note for the OP.  Intersect is limited to 2 vectors.  Use the `Reduce` function to intersect a larger collection declared in a list.  `common <- Reduce(intersect, list(x, y, z))`

Answer (score 1):

A useful short-hand for this problem is to subset `x` according to `x %in% y`. This will return every value where x is one of the values in y. `unique` is used to remove duplicate elements.

```r
x <- c("a", "b", "c", "a")
y <- c("a", "d", "f")

print(x %in% y)

#> [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE

unique(x[x %in% y])

#> [1] "a"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>